# How to implement some process'es steps in controller actions staying restful?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, model-view-controller, routes

Webapp (RoR) I'm working on now need to guide user through some process steps. It needs to be implemented with ajax requests so I can change only the part of a form.
I want to create custom actions in my controller for every step and create *.js.erb accordingly to render parts of the form incrementally 
I know that it'll work quite seamlessly but there always was some anxiety worm in my head about this approach. Am I missing some cool pattern for implementing incremental actions being RESTfull?

Comment: Maybe this link can help you: http://railscasts.com/episodes/346-wizard-forms-with-wicked

Comment: @sailor thank you! that is an option!